# Can I authenticate Salesforce REST API with existing SOAP API session?

Tags: salesforce

I'm put in an awkward place where a project is using both Salesforce's SOAP API and REST API. I'm not in a position to budge either group to merging to use the other, but I'm trying to at least move the authentication piece into one place.

If possible, I would like to use my existing SOAP API's session to authenticate the REST app instead of storing those credentials in two appendages of the same site/app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible. A SessionId that you get from a SOAP api login call can be used to make calls to the REST api.